# What are the best proofs of Cavalieri's principle without concepts of calculus?

Tags: integration, euclidean-geometry, volume

What are the best proofs of Cavalieri's principle without concepts of calculus?

"Best" may be construed as most cogent from the point of view of students of elementary geometry, or as most elegant, or in any other reasonable sense.

Comment: I guess you consider proof by pictures as valid? I think rigorous proofs are not possible because you might not even be able to state the theorem without calculus (measure theory)

Comment: @M.Winter : I expect there are versions of Cavalieri's principle that can be proved without going into sigma-algebras or the like.

Comment: Well I am very curious. +1

Comment: IIRC, Archimedes used a generalization of Cavalieri's principle. There might have been a proof by exhaustion; I don't recall. (I suppose if you reiterate the statement of the principle a sufficient number of times, the students who object to the lack of proof will become exhausted, but that is a different kind of proof by exhaustion.)

Comment: It's quite unclear to me what it means to even rigorously state Cavalieri's principle without some form of calculus, since otherwise I don't know what is meant rigorously by volume.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : I don't think it's a good idea to let that kind of unclarity stop you dead in your tracks. Rigor should often be the last step, not the first. $\qquad$

Comment: I'm thinking some kind of argument from squeezing might be good.

Comment: [Coming up in this new series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cINtOxgDWNc).

Answer (score 3):

There is a proof of Cavalieri's principle by Minkowski on [pages 204-207](https://archive.org/stream/geometriederzahl00minkuoft#page/204/mode/2up) of his book "Geometrie der Zahlen", published in 1896. Minkowski needed it because Fubini's theorem did not exist then. The proof is quite elementary (he covers the body with a net of cubes), but of course he uses concepts from analysis by letting the sidelength of the cubes go to zero.